# Is MediaFire API app bound to the user who created it?

Tags: api, mediafire

If I create MediaFire API app, can anyone who knows the app_id use it with their own email and password as in the snippet below? Or only my email and password would work?

```py
from mediafire import MediaFireApi
api = MediaFireApi()
session = api.user_get_session_token(
    email='YOUR_EMAIL',
    password='YOUR_PASSWORD',
    app_id='42511')
```

Comment: It looks like there's no way to create MediaFire API app anyway...